# Зазубрины на спрайтах

Tags: unity3d

Я создаю 2D игру на unity когда я запускаю её на смартфоне то у маленького круга появляются "зазубрины", можно же как-то исправить, но как? Вот в других играх из Google play я видел что даже на самых маленьких спрайтах не видно никаких зазубрин!

Исходная текстура круга разрешением 1024x1024 в unity до маленьких размеров.

Comment: Увеличь разрешение круга.

Comment: @Dodik 1024x1024 и при этом уменьшено в unity до маленьких размеров

Comment: Лучше не увеличивать и не уменьшать, а взять спрайт 1 к 1 как вам нужно. Когда вы увеличиваете или уменьшаете изображение в игре - это приводит к использованию специальных фильтров (почитайте в интернете про фильтры минификации и магнификации). Собственно использование этих фильтров может и часто дает артефакты, потому что например у вас было 1млн пикселей, а из него вы хотите получить 16к - в тупую вы выкинуть их не сможете, по этому придется аппроксимировать цвет

Comment: @vmchar Ха и правда как 1 к 1 всё сделал так всё стало хорошо смотреться! А как же сделать для UI? Ведь там нужно на несколько размеров больше так как оно будет подстраиваться к размерам экранов!

Comment: исследуй возможности канваса и автоскейла

Comment: В Ui используют разные техники, например тайлинг. Вообще подобного рода артефакты больше всего видны как раз на закругленных объекта или на градиентах. Если правильно нарезать UI (отрезать 4 загругленных угла и а наполнение панели затайлить) то подобных артефактов можно избежать. + чем больше уменьшается/увеличивается изображение - тем больше артефактов. Думаю, будет большая разница между 1024*1024 -> 128*128 и 256*256 -> 128*128

Comment: @AimonZ. оформил нашу переписку в ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел мертвым грузом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы избежать подобных неприятных эффектов используйте изображение 1 к 1 относительно того размера, который вам нужен, без увеличения или уменьшения.

Проблема в том, что вы используете текстуру в нее ее родном разрешении. Для увеличения или уменьшения текстур в реальном времени игровые движки (и конкретные драйвера) используют фильтры. Эти фильтры - алгоритмы для преобразования изображения из одного размера в другой. Так как мы не можем изменить размер изображения без потерь качества (особенно в реальном времени), результатом этой операции являются разного рода артефакты.

На примере OpenGL, можно посмотреть (скажем в [этой статье](http://what-when-how.com/opengl-programming-guide/filtering-texture-mapping-opengl-programming/)) используются фильтры `GL_TEXTURE_.MAG_FILTER` для увеличения изображения по сравнению с исходным размером и `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` для уменьшения. К каждому из этих фильтров могут быть применены значения `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`, обозначающие разные алгоритмы.

При увеличении изображения как и при уменьшении общим побочным эффектом является "убийство" градиентов (цвета начинают не так плавно переходить из одного в другой) и размытие границ изображения (в местах, где цветные области переходя в прозрачные). Самым частым эффектом при увеличении изображения также является размытие (похожее на блюр).

Для примера возьмем картинку:

[image: исходное изображение]

А теперь применим увеличение (магнификацию):

[image: увеличенный фрагмент] Видим размытие границ и потерю цвета на контуре.

И уменьшение (минификацию):
[image: уменьшенное изображение] Если приблизить картинку артефакты будут отчетливо видны - форма объекта стала угловатой и зернистой.

Это происходит, потому что если у вас есть изображение 1024*1024 пикселей и вы хотите уменьшить его до 128*128 это равносильно тому, что вы из 1 048 576 пикселей, хотите, чтобы осталось 16 384 пикселей. В этот момент происходит следующее: берется группа пикселей изображения и их цвета аппроксимируются таким образом, чтобы получить меньшее число пикселей, Например изображение делится на квадраты 3*3 пикселя и они преобразуются в квадраты 2*2 пикселя:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как конкретно аппроксимируется цвет выходного пикселя как раз и зависит от выбранного алгоритма минификации.